# Angular.js and Node.js - Passing input variables through controller to server.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, routes, mean-stack

Just learning the MEAN stack at the moment, and I'm fiddling around with it but I'm a little lost.

What I'm trying to achieve is to utilize an external API to auto fill input fields about the tag that is initially typed.

[image: route info]

**So the question is, how do I pass the value of `foo` all the way to `server.js` for the call?**

1. End-user enters a `tag` and presses 'Get Data'
2. Controller passes the value of `tag` *(defined in my `.ejs` file as `ng-model="object.tag"`)* to the `getData` route
3. `server.js` takes `tag` and passes it into the external API URL to call
4. External API does its thing, returns with a nice and pretty `JSON` file for me.
5. Controller auto populates as many form fields as it can from the returned JSON.

Here are a few code bits just so you understand the structure of what I have a little more:

**--index.ejs--**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="object.tag" />
<button ng-click="grabFooInfo()">Get Data</button>
```

**--controller.js--**

```
$scope.grabFooInfo = function(){
    $http.get('/getData').success(function(res){
        // Will do stuff here after data comes back
    });
};
```

**--server.js--**

```
app.get('/getData', function (req, res) {
    var options = {
        host: 'my.api.im.calling.com,
        path: '/v1/fooApi/' + // #Need foo here //
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json"
        },
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function (response) {
        var fooData = '';
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            fooData += data;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            res.send(fooData);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

- **Am I doing my routing properly for how Node is intended to work?**
- **How do I pass an input value to this internal function in `server.js` using Angular?**

Answer (score 1):

In client side,
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="object.tag" />
<button ng-click="grabFooInfo(object)">Get Data</button>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.grabFooInfo = function(object){
    $http({
        url:'/getData', 
        method: "GET",
        params: object
     });
});
```

In Server Side,

```
app.get('/getData', function (req, res) {
   var data = req.params.data; // it contains the value foo
})
```

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: when the response comes back he will need to call `$scope.$apply` for the data to be updated on the controller

Comment: Well, it's not going to be foo, I was using that as an example. It's an input field. So somebody will be typing "#992823" (or some other acceptable tag for the external API). I need to pass the value from the form.

Comment: @NicholasHazel i made it generic!!  this solved your question??

Comment: Hmm, still coming up undefined in my server console when I console.log the value of `data` after declaring it. Doesn't seem to be taking the input value of `ng-model="object.tag"`

Comment: in server console or browser console??

Comment: Server console. I can't figure out how to pass the value from `ng-model="object.tag"` to controller.js to then pass to server.js

Comment: ng-click="grabFooInfo(object)", this will take the values into controller

Comment: I have that on my .ejs file. Its not passing them along.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105138/discussion-between-raja-sekar-and-nicholas-hazel).